# Help with some code

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I got stuck solving the following problem:

```
Table[Table[
  Table[
   g1Size = x; g2Size = y;
   vals = 
    FindInstance[(a1 - a2) - (b1 - b2) == z && a1 + b1 == g1Size && 
      a2 + b2 == g2Size && a1 + a2 == g1Size && b1 + b2 == g2Size && 
      a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0, {a1, a2, b1, b2}, 
     Integers, 3];
   aa1 = a1 /. vals; aa2 = a2 /. vals; bb1 = b1 /. vals; 
   bb2 = b2 /. vals;
   {g1Size, g2Size, z, Flatten@{aa1, aa2, bb1, bb2}}
   , {z, 0, 10}], {x, 1, 10}], {y, 1, 10}]
```

I want to loop through different values of g1Size, g2Size and z and find the first solution to the system of equations. As soon as a solution for a combination of g1Size,g2size and z was found, I want to extract the values for a1,a2,b1,b2 and continue with the next loop. In other words, only print the values when vals is not empty and then stop the z-loop and switch to the next values of x and y.

But my output is like this:

```
{{{{1, 1, 0, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 1, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 
    2, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 3, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 
    4, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 5, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 
    6, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 7, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 
    8, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 9, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}, {1, 1, 
    10, {a1, a2, b1, b2}}}
```

plotting the names for a1,a2,b1,b2 when no solution was found.

My mathematica coding is a bit rust and this code seems far from elegant. And I hope it is clear what I mean :).

Comment: Why do you ask for 3 instances with the last argument to `FindInstance`, when you say that you want to switch to the next value of `z` "As soon as a solution for a combination of g1Size,g2size and z was found (...)"? Do you want 3 instances for each `{g1Size, g2Size, z}`, or just 1?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to change that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. If you don't know how many results a piece of code will give, you
   can use `Reap` and `Sow` to collect the results you want.
2. If you want to break from the loop over `z`, simply use `Break[]` within an appropriate `If` test.

I would do the following:

```
ans = Reap[
   Do[
    Do[
     instances = 
      FindInstance[(a1 - a2) - (b1 - b2) == z && a1 + b1 == g1Size && 
        a2 + b2 == g2Size && a1 + a2 == g1Size && b1 + b2 == g2Size &&
         a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0, {a1, a2, b1, b2}, 
       Integers];
     If[instances =!= {},
      Sow[{g1Size, g2Size, z, {a1, a2, b1, b2} /. instances}]; 
      Break[]
      ]
     , {z, 0, 10}]
    , {g1Size, 1, 10}, {g2Size, 1, 10}]
    ];
```

The results are found with `ans[[2,1]]`, which gives a list that's a bit too long to reproduce here :)

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you! Didn't know about Reap and sow, so this works pretty well :)

Answer (score 1):

This may me done a bit faster (speed increases by factor 4; there may be potential for more increase) by doing it the *functional way*:

```
rangeX = rangeY = Range[10];

(* the function fz will find exactly on solution given z ∈ [0,10] if it exists *)
fz = Function[ {g1Size, g2Size},
    With[
      {
        sol = FindInstance[
          (a1 - a2) - (b1 - b2) == z
          && a1 + b1 == g1Size
          && a2 + b2 == g2Size
          && a1 + a2 == g1Size
          && b1 + b2 == g2Size
          && a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 &&  0 <= z <= 10,
          {z, a1, a2, b1, b2},
          Integers
        ]
      },
      If[ sol === {},
          (* then *)
          Nothing,
          (* else *)
          { g1Size, g2Size, z, {a1, a2, b1, b2}} /. sol 
      ]
    ]
];

solList = Outer[ fz[ #1, #2]&, rangeX, rangeY] // Flatten[ #, 2 ]&;

Short@solList
```

> {{2,2,0,{1,1,1,1}},{2,3,1,{1,1,1,2}},<<77>>,{10,9,3,{6,4,4,5}},{10,10,0,{5,5,5,5}}}

**References:**

- [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html)
- [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html)
- [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html)
- [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)
- [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

Comment: Since you are only interested in one instance of `z` you may include `z`in the `FindInstance[...]` expression so no additional loop needed.

Comment: Insighful :), thank you!